# Custom Options Automatically Delete in Back End

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

We keep adding custom options manually to certain products in the back end of Magento.  However, whenever we add them, they disappear automatically in the back end and of course never show up in the front end.  They're just nowhere to be found, like they were never there.

We also noticed that these products used to have custom options that are now deleted.  Nobody recalls deleting them.

Please let me know if you need more info & thank you in advance!  Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check for a javascript error in the browser console.

If the custom options block doesn't load correctly, it basically loads up blank. So a product resave could potentially wipe these out.